# Handling a toggled onclick with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of text, that I wish to show truncated, but when clicked it will expand to show the rest. Clicking again should truncate it.

I was trying to use the onclick event to handle this as follows (**WARNING**: Do not run following code without reading below...):

```
<span id='blah' onclick='showAllComment("this is a long comment to see it all", 9, true )'>this is a...</span>

<script>
function showAllComment( comment, shortCommentLen, showFullComment )
{
    alert( $("#blah").html() );

    if( showFullComment )
    {
        $("#blah").html( comment );
        $("#blah").click( showAllComment( comment, shortCommentLen, false ) );
    }
    else
    {
        $("#blah").html( comment.substring( 0, shortCommentLen ) + "..." );
        $("#blah").click( showAllComment( comment, shortCommentLen, true ) );
    }
}
</script>
```

But as you will see, it repeatedly calls itself and you have to end task the browser (so be careful when running this code!!!!)

Can anyone suggest why this is happening, and what to do to resolve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: <abbr title="The very long description">The short</abbr>

Comment: Good point, but I dont think a truncated comment is actually an 'abbreviation', it would be abusing the purest definition of the tag I think, what does anyone else think, is that being to purest??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are recursively invoking the `showAllComment` function

Try doing something like this instead:

```
function showAllComment( comment, shortCommentLen, showFullComment )
{
    alert( $("#blah").html() );

    if( showFullComment )
    {
        $("#blah").html( comment );
        $("#blah").click( function () { showAllComment(comment, shortCommentLen, false);} );
    }
    else
    {
        $("#blah").html( comment.substring( 0, shortCommentLen ) + "..." );
        $("#blah").click( function () {showAllComment( comment, shortCommentLen, true );} );
    }
}
```

That way you are enclosing the invocation inside of an anonymous function, so it will get executed once you click the `#bla` element only.

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot Dreas. However, I have just noticed an issue with this solution. JQuery doesnt replace the bound event, it adds to it, so you get increasing functions being called each time its clicked. Using the DOM works fine:   document.getElementById("blah").onclick = function() {...};

Answer (score 2):

Users without javascript enabled will be unable to read the comment. A better approach would be to include the whole comment in the `span` and make the javascript truncate it when the page loads:

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".blah").each( function() {
        var shortCommentLen = 9;
        var comment = $(this).html();                   
        $(this).html(shortComment(comment, shortCommentLen));
        $(this).toggle(
            function() { $(this).html(comment); },
            function() { $(this).html(shortComment(comment, shortCommentLen)); }
        );

        function shortComment(comment, shortCommentLen) {
            return comment.substring( 0, shortCommentLen ) + "...";
        }
    });
});
```

html:

```
<span class='blah'>this is a long comment to see it all</span>
```

The `toggle(fn1, fn2)` function altenates between two functions when the element is clicked.

Comment: Yes sure, in my solution its okay as its on an ajax powered popup so JS is essential for its viewing anyway, but I like your alternative.